# Manage Inventory Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good Morning,

I have the following dataset:

```
print(df)

Date        Type of Operation     Quantity         
01/01/17      Order                  5
01/01/17      Sale                   3
02/01/17      Sale                   1
02/01/17      Order                  5
```

I would like to create the following column:

```
print(df_1)

Date        Type of Operation     Quantity     Actual_Inventory    
01/01/17      Order                  5                5
01/01/17      Sale                   3                2
02/01/17      Sale                   1                1
02/01/17      Order                  5                6
```

Any suggestion about how to code it using Python and pandas?
Thank you

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this yourself?

Comment: I did, but I was missing the -1 in mask()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiple column `Quantity` by `-1` if `Sale` and then use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
m = df['Type of Operation'] == 'Sale' 
df['Actual_Inventory'] = df['Quantity'].mask(m, df['Quantity'] * -1).cumsum()
```

Another solution:

```
a = (df['Type of Operation'] == 'Sale').map({True:-1, False:1})
df['Actual_Inventory'] = df['Quantity'].mul(a).cumsum()
```

---

```
print (df)
       Date Type of Operation  Quantity  Actual_Inventory
0  01/01/17             Order         5                 5
1  01/01/17              Sale         3                 2
2  02/01/17              Sale         1                 1
3  02/01/17             Order         5                 6
```